# YouTube API analytics - video dimension report for all channel videos

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, google-analytics-api

We are looking to get a report:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/available_reports
dimensions:country
filter:videoId
for ALL our videos.

In order to do that we getting all our videos
(https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list)

and looping through each video (we need the breakdown per country for each video)

the question
1. is that the best way to go?
2. we are not getting the private videos since the search does not return them but the analytics page in youtube does take them into consideration so we have a data mismatch.

any help would be appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: I have tried what you suggested and no luck. I am getting only the public video and not the "private","unlisted" ones. i need those since they do exist in the YouTube Analytics data.

Comment: it works! had to set "auth" in the test console. only one problem remains and that is the the title i am getting is "private video" and not the actual title. thx@

Answer (score 0):

To get your videos, you can use [channels->list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list) 'with mine=true' and get relatedPlaylists

or

[playLists->list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists/list) with your channelId and 'mine=true'

then

you can go through these videos with [playlistItems->list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list)

Answer (score 0):

As of Aug 28, 2014 it is now possible to fetch metrics for up to 200 videos per API call. See information here:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/revision_history